# How do I turn row data into column data in pandas, while repeating and shifting dates at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for the vague question, it was hard to know how to phrase it.

I have a DataFrame that looks like the following, where each `STORE/PRODUCT` combination will have a continuous date range associated with it:

```
DATE       | STORE | PRODUCT | UNITS_SOLD |  
-------------------------------------------
2020-01-01 |     1 | Beans   | 10         |
2020-01-02 |     1 | Beans   | 5          |
2020-01-03 |     1 | Beans   | 6          |
2020-01-01 |     2 | Carrots | 6          |
2020-01-02 |     2 | Carrots | 7          |
2020-01-03 |     2 | Carrots | 3          |
...        |   ... | ...     | ...        |
```

I'd like to transform this into the following DataFrame, where:

- Every original date for each `STORE/PRODUCT` combination is still present in its own row, thus becoming the row's start date
- Future dates (relabelled) relative to the start date for each `STORE/PRODUCT` combination are the column headers
- `UNITS_SOLD` are the values

This DataFrame would look like this:

```
STORE | PRODUCT | DATE       | UNITS_SOLD_NEXT_1_DAYS | UNITS_SOLD_NEXT_2_DAYS | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | Beans   | 2020-01-01 | 5                      | 6                      |
1     | Beans   | 2020-01-02 | 6                      | NaN                    |
1     | Beans   | 2020-01-03 | NaN                    | NaN                    |
2     | Carrots | 2020-01-01 | 7                      | 3                      |
2     | Carrots | 2020-01-02 | 3                      | NaN                    |
2     | Carrots | 2020-01-03 | NaN                    | NaN                    |
...   | ...     | ...        | ...                    | ...                    |
```

I can get a single row for each `STORE/PRODUCT` combination by using `df.pivot_table()` but I'm having trouble with the repeated rows with staggered values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the most robust or prettiest looking solution, but it seems like some fancy numpy indexing will get you there.

```
def waterfall(series):
    units_sold = series.to_numpy()
    n_days = units_sold.shape[0]
      
    shape = (n_days, n_days)
    out = np.full(shape, np.nan)
    r, c = np.triu_indices(n_days)    
    out[r, c-r] = np.take(units_sold, c)
    
    columns = ["next_{}_days".format(i) for i in range(1, n_days)]
    columns.insert(0, "units_sold")
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns=columns)

    

new_df = (df.groupby(["store", "product"])["units_sold"]
          .apply(waterfall)
          .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
          .set_index(df.date, append=True)
         )

print(new_df)
                          units_sold  next_1_days  next_2_days  next_3_days
store product date                                                         
1     Beans   2020-01-01        10.0          5.0          6.0          NaN
              2020-01-02         5.0          6.0          NaN          NaN
              2020-01-03         6.0          NaN          NaN          NaN
2     Carrots 2020-01-01         6.0          7.0          3.0          9.0
              2020-01-02         7.0          3.0          9.0          NaN
              2020-01-03         3.0          9.0          NaN          NaN
              2020-01-04         9.0          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

This solution doesn't take consecutive days into account, just consecutive observations. So if the days within a store aren't consecutive, then your column titles may be off. Hopefully this does the trick though!